# Im trying to see when all the letters have been discoved in Hangman but it is just not working

Tags: python

I have been testing it with just the work TEST and have every letter converting to uppercase for it to register. The part I am having trouble with is:

```
if Counter(guesses) == Counter(testw):

   winner = 1

   break
```

All I want it to do is break out of the while loop and maybe print a message. I have tried to do something I saw online with the counter but it didnt work which is why that counter thing is there (even though I don't really understand it).

```
import random
import os
import time
from collections import Counter 

#someWords = '''apple banana mango strawberry  
#orange grape pineapple apricot lemon coconut watermelon 
#cherry papaya berry peach lychee muskmelon'''

#someWords = someWords.split(' ') 
#word = random.choice(someWords)  

testw = "TEST"
point = 0

print("Welcome to Hangman!")

winner = 0
guesses = ''
wrong = ''
total = 0
while point < 6:


    if point == 0:
        print("-----I\n     I\n     I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 1:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n     I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 2:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n  |  I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 3:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|  I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 4:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 5:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n   \ I\n========")
    if point == 6:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n  /\ I\n========")

    for char in testw:
        if char in guesses:
            print(char, end = ' ')
        else:
            print('_ ', end = '')



    print("\n")
    print('You have ', 6-point, ' guesses left!')
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")


    guess = str.upper(guess)
    guesses += guess

    if guess not in testw:
        print("Wrong!")
        point += 1
        guess += wrong
    if guess in testw:
        print("Correct!")
        guesses += guess
    total += 1

    if Counter(guesses) == Counter(testw):
        winner = 1
        break
#end
if winner == 1:
    print("Winner")
else:
    print("You Lose")
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two issues here which are causing your `wincheck` to always fail.

In future, it is handy to utilise `print()` when you encounter errors that require you to exit a loop based on a condition, as it is likely the check is failing.

You have added the guessed letter to the variable you're using to check for victory before checking if the letter is correct.

```
guess = str.upper(guess)

guesses += guess
```

When you resolve this, you are not storing multiple letters if they're found. You only add one instance to `guesses`

```
if guess in testw:
        print("Correct!")
        for letter in testw:
            if letter.upper() == guess.upper():
                guesses += guess
```

The above code will fix this, by iterating over every letter in the correct word, and adding the letter to the `guesses` string each time it is found.

All in all, the below code fixes both of these issues.

```
import random
import os
import time
from collections import Counter 

#someWords = '''apple banana mango strawberry  
#orange grape pineapple apricot lemon coconut watermelon 
#cherry papaya berry peach lychee muskmelon'''

#someWords = someWords.split(' ') 
#word = random.choice(someWords)  

testw = "TEST"
point = 0

print("Welcome to Hangman!")

winner = 0
guesses = ''
wrong = ''
total = 0
while point < 6:


    if point == 0:
        print("-----I\n     I\n     I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 1:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n     I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 2:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n  |  I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 3:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|  I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 4:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n     I\n========")
    if point == 5:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n   \ I\n========")
    if point == 6:
        print("-----I\n  O  I\n /|\ I\n  /\ I\n========")

    for char in testw:
        if char in guesses:
            print(char, end = ' ')
        else:
            print('_ ', end = '')



    print("\n")
    print('You have ', 6-point, ' guesses left!')
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")


    guess = str.upper(guess)

    if guess not in testw:
        print("Wrong!")
        point += 1
        guess += wrong
    if guess in testw:
        print("Correct!")
        for letter in testw:
            if letter.upper() == guess.upper():
                guesses += guess
    total += 1

    if Counter(guesses) == Counter(testw):
        winner = 1
        break

#end
if winner == 1:
    print("Winner")
else:
    print("You Lose")
```